# How do I restore a contact I deleted on my Android phone, but not in GMail contacts?

Tags: contacts, sync

The contact in question had the wrong phone number in Viber, so I deleted it from Viber. I later found out that Viber had deleted it from my contacts, so I had lost all of the other correct information.

Logging in to GMail contacts on the desktop showed that the contact still existed. I proceeded to correct the faulty phone number and tried to sync my contacts from my phone, but this particular contact never shows up.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Are you sure it removed it from the phone and you're not just using the "only show contacts with phone numbers" setting? Is the Gmail contact record in the "My Contacts" group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**
Stop syncing with Google account, check that all Google contacts are gone, set up sync again.

**Method 2**
Remove the Google account, add it again.

(You can do both in Accounts & Sync from phone Settings.)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting and clearing your Contacts Storage (SETTINGS > APPLICATIONS > MANAGE APPLICATIONS - SHOW ALL) and re-syncing. One good thing about Google's Gmail Contacts - it retains backup sets, so you can restore previously modified / deleted contacts from within the Gmail web interface.

Or you can try creating a fresh contact with the same info and slightly changed details, like adding a comma within the postal address or adding a prefix like Mr. / Ms. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating it on the phone instead, maybe just enough to make a valid entry, say name and phone # (bogus # if need be), then sync. If it takes, then fix it on Gmail from your computer.