# How to recover deleted contacts

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, data-recovery

I lost all my contacts while syncing  email.Is there a way to recover these contacts.
I checked on Google contacts in Gmail but its not there as I never synced my contacts.
Not rooted and Android version is Gingerbread 2.3

Comment: What about restoring your backup you hopefully made? Apart from that, they are most likely gone for good (except you want to hire an expensive recovery expert, in which case you shouldn't touch your device until he's done his job). Is your device rooted? Then you might want to take a look at e.g. [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25948/16575)

Comment: There seem to be a number of similar questions in the "Related" section (on the right). Did you look into any of them? I expect this is a duplicate. [I lost all my contacts on Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35520) [How to recover lost contacts from samsung galaxy s3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44383) [How do I restore a contact I deleted on my Android phone, but not in GMail contacts?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15419)

Comment: @AlEverett I have gone through all the questions before posting this question.
The problem is I never created a backup ,Is there any feature in Gingerbread that automatically creates backup?